# Not fully specified template as template argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates

In curiously recurring template pattern I need to change nested type `T` of `TDerivedClass<T>` type. Is there a way to specify `Base` by not fully specified `Derived1` class? Something like that: `class Derived1 : public Base<T, Derived1<"NOT SPECIFIED TYPE SYNTAX">>`, and then fully specify `Derived1` but inside `Base` functions as `TDerivedClass<int>`. Or is there any other way to change `T` for this specific part of code?

```
template<typename T, typename TDerivedClass>
class Base
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::vector<T> a;
        TDerivedClass b;
        TDerivedClass<int> c; // <- want to change T to arbitrary type (to int for example) without changing T
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T, Derived1<T>>
{

};

template<typename T>
class Derived2 : public Base<T, Derived2<T>>
{

};
```

Comment: You probably want template template parameter. or maybe something similar to `std::allocator::rebind<U>`.

Comment: I can't fully understand _`// <- want to change T to arbitrary type (int for example) without changing T`_? What do you want to achieve here, what's the use case?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In most code TDerivedClass<T> is used, but in some cases I have function for comparision of TDerivedClass<T> and TDerivedClass<> with arbitrary other T

Comment: So why not using template specialization and maybe SFINAE in first place? `TDerivedClass<int> c;` is a runtime thing, but shouldn't.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly. But if `int` is the problem, why can you not make it a template parameter to Base? If that's not the case and you want `int` to be part of Derived then probably you need something like Jarod42's suggestion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ template specialization is only for specific types, I don't want to list all possible T types.

Comment: @Yury _"template specialization is only for specific types"_ Yes. _"I don't want to list all possible T types."_ You shouldn't have to, you can use `std::enable_if` stuff, to point out what specifically should be specialized, there are even helpers to [determine categories of `T](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the template class specifically:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class TDerivedTemplate>
class Base
{
    using TDerivedClass = TDerivedTemplate<T>;
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::vector<T> a;
        TDerivedClass b;
        TDerivedTemplate<int> c;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T, Derived1>  // Pass the template (Derived1) to instantiate new classes from
{

};

// Since you're changing the pattern anyways, you might as well
// have it detect the template from the type

template<typename TDerivedClass>
class Base;

template<template<typename> class TDerivedTemplate, typename T>
class Base<TDerivedTemplate<T>> {
    using TDerivedClass = TDerivedTemplate<T>;
public:
    void f() { /* Same as above */ }
}

template<typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1<T>>
// Automatically gets the template. Also means it's harder to use Base<> wrong.
{

};
```

Or you can use a `rebind` type trait:

```
template<typename ToRebind, typename... NewTypes>
struct rebind;

template<template<typename...> class Template, typename... CurrentTypes, typename... NewTypes>
struct rebind<Template<CurrentTypes...>, NewTypes...> {
    using type = Template<NewTypes...>;
}

// Used like
    TDerivedClass b;
    typename rebind<TDerivedClass, int>::type c;
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want template template parameter:

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class TDerivedClass>
class Base
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        std::vector<T> a;
        TDerivedClass<T> b;
        TDerivedClass<int> c;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived1 : public Base<T, Derived1>
{

};

template<typename T>
class Derived2 : public Base<T, Derived2>
{

};
```